# How to delete every nth column in excel without macro?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have data in excel.
  I would like to delete columns 1,2,15,16,29,30... and so on. (2 consecutive columns every 14)
How would I go about deleting these columns WITHOUT USING A MACRO?

Answer (score 1):

Add a row at the top with:

```
=IF(OR(MOD(COLUMN(),14)=1,MOD(COLUMN(),14)=2),"z","")
```

copied across to suit. Then sort on row1 and delete surplus columns.